# How to improve the C++ STL bitset efficiency?

Tags: c++, performance, stl, bitset, lookup-tables

I have a program that heavily uses STL's `bitset`. And gperftools shows that one of the performance bottle neck is `std::_Base_bitset::_S_maskbit` (inline).

From here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00775_source.html#l00078 it seem a mask for accessing or modifying a `bitset` is always recomputed. This makes me wonder if a look-up table would help.

I tried to implement my own version of `bitset`, where a mask look-up table is used. However since my version does not use gcc built-in instructions like `__builtin_memcpy`, it is actually much slower than the STL `bitset`.

So I wonder if there is a way to replace `std::_Base_bitset::_S_maskbit`, or should I write my own version of `bitset` by copying the code of STL `bitset` and adding a look-up table.

Thanks!

Comment: First, are you timing an optimized build?

Comment: Modern processors are much faster at computing a value than they are at fetching a value from memory. Lookup tables are hardly ever an improvement.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  The program compiled with O2.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Hmmm I didn't know this...very interesting to know. Thanks.

Comment: [Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832)

Comment: @MarkRansom: That's quite a generalization. It's probably true in this case - bitlevel operations are among the fastest - but floating-point operations can be quite slow. In fact, for many FP functions you'd need to retrieve half a dozen coefficients or more, which make a single invocation slower than a LUT access.

Comment: @MarkRansom Generally you are right but during an inner loop the table may just fit in the L1 cache...

Comment: @PeterSchneider: That's still slower than the single-cycle bit shift you'd need here.

Comment: @MSalters _S_maskbit does a modulo and then a shift.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: It's of course a power-of-two modulo, and probably done after `_S_whichword`. You probably get it for free. And on Intel it's definitely for free as the CPU will do the modulo for you (it only uses the lowest 5 bits of the shift count, upper bits are a don't care)

Answer (score 2):

If your bitsets are sufficiently small, using a `std::vector<char>` can be an improvement. Sure, you use 8 times the memory, but you wouldn't need to calculate masks anymore and profiling showed that's relevant for you.

Accessing arrays is pretty fast on x86 due to its good support for addressing modes and prefetchers, but bitsets are more the domain of ARM where many operations can include a free bitshift.

Comment: My bitset contains 400 bits.

Comment: I once discovered while working with bitmap images that it was quicker to expand each 8 bits into 8 bytes, do my operations, and repack, than it was to work with the bitmap directly.

Comment: Considering 400 bytes still fits in L1 cache, I wouldn't be surprised if this is a similar case.

Answer (score 0):

From the link it seems the recomputing of the mask bit (_S_maskbit) is just a left shift followed by a modular operation, which (if _GLIBCXX_BITSET_BITS_PER_WORD is a power of 2) could have been optimized by the compiler as a logic-AND. So the complexity of recomputing the bit is really low, probably lower than accessing a lookup table.

Given that the function is inline and relatively short, gperf may not be accurate in profiling it. Or perhaps the __pos % _GLIBCXX_BITSET_BITS_PER_WORD could not be optimized as __pos & (_GLIBCXX_BITSET_BITS_PER_WORD - 1), in which case operator% would probably be the most expensive operation here.